# Define global variable to use in multiple source files

Tags: c, header-files

I have a variable that I intend to use in multiple files, is a mutex initializer.

So I wrote in one header file this :

```
#ifndef LISTEN_H_
#define LISTEN_H_

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

#endif
```

I tried to include the header in the files in witch I intend to use the variable.

But i get : error mutex has already been declared here.

What is the proper way to use a global variable in multiple header files ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way would be to **define it in a `.c` file** and **declare it as `extern` in the header file**. Now you would be able to use it wherever you want to use it, without errors.

Comment: then whats the purpose of header guard..?

Comment: @Mr.32 the include guard prevents the file from being included multiple times IN THE SAME translation unit - i.e during compilation.

Comment: @Mr.32 This error, is due to multiple copies of the variables defined in different translation units - during linking stage.

Comment: @KarthikT oh OP hasnt specify that in question still u get it..great +1